# Importing a zip file and getting individual files in it, using Webpack

Tags: node.js, xml, webpack, zip

I have a standard `webpack` environment set up, and I am using ES6 imports with `npm` packages (the usual `import name from 'package'`). I'm using `webpack-dev-server` as my dev environment, and the standard `webpack` build for building the output directory.

I have a zip file in my source containing a large number of XML files, and in my JS program, I want to be able to read that zip file in and be able to extract individual files from it, so I can get the text from those files and process the XML in them.

I am currently using the `xmldoc` package for transforming XML text to a JSON object for processing, but I have not been able to find a reliable package for reading in a zip file (using the path to the file) and being able to get the individual files in it. In the ones I have tried, I have run into trouble with `node`'s `fs` module. If I try adding the `target: 'node'` property to my `webpack` config file, I receive an error stating `require is not defined`.

Is there a reliable npm package compatible with ES6 imports that can read a zip file into my program? I realize that means the zip must be included in the build files to be sent to the browser, but that is better than including the hundreds of individual files without zipping them. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you want [browserfs](https://github.com/jvilk/browserfs). Here is example code from the readme. You will also need to do some config for webpack (check the readme):

```
fetch('mydata.zip').then(function(response) {
  return response.arrayBuffer();
}).then(function(zipData) {
  var Buffer = BrowserFS.BFSRequire('buffer').Buffer;

  BrowserFS.configure({
    fs: "MountableFileSystem",
    options: {
      "/zip": {
        fs: "ZipFS",
        options: {
          // Wrap as Buffer object.
          zipData: Buffer.from(zipData)
        }
      },
      "/tmp": { fs: "InMemory" },
      "/home": { fs: "IndexedDB" }
    }
  }, function(e) {
    if (e) {
      // An error occurred.
      throw e;
    }
    // Otherwise, BrowserFS is ready to use!
  });
});
```